# Is sample skewness statistically significant?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, econometrics, skewness, moments

I've been searching for a research that would examine statistical significance of a sample skewness between two financial time series of returns. Unfortunately, I was not able to find any good or relevant references, so please share them if you know some.

Given a series of returns $r_t$, $j$-th central moment is defined as $\mu_j = E\left[r_t - E(r_t)\right]^j$ and skewness is defined as
$$skew = \frac{\mu_3}{\mu_2^{3/2}}.$$

I've done some simulation studies where I assume a certain data generating process and test for $H_0: \text{skewness difference is zero}$ and found that an error rate even at $10\%$ confidence level is very high, meaning that it is hard to find two time series that would provide evidence of statistically significant difference. However, I would be interested in studying a more thorough research. I would be interested in a research that does not focus on financial market data as well.

Comment: (1) How do you measure "skewness" (there are several in common use)?  (2) How would conducting a hypothesis test of skewness have any value in this kind of application?  It seems like an indirect proxy to address a more fundamental question, perhaps related to the chances of unexpectedly large losses or gains.  Are you sure you really need to be pursuing this issue?

Comment: @whuber I added a definition for skewness. My application is monte carlo simulations of financial time series which are done by fitting models with GMM (and hence fitting to sample skewness among others). Given noisy structure of financial data, I want to justify whether moments of two time series are statistically different.

Comment: What do you mean by “statistically different”?

Comment: @Dave By statistically different I mean that a statistic $skew_1 - skew_2$ is statistically different from zero at a given confidence level.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by “statistically different”?